Qt theming and appmenu issues
I have a couple of problems with Qt5/Qt6 applications.

I have installed xfce4-appmenu-plugin vala-panel-appmenu and vala-panel-appmenu-common packages. I have configured xfce4 specific settings with xfconf-query as mentioned in vala's github page. I have added the AppMenu Plugin in my xfce4 panel settings. Now all application menubars show up in the panel. The only problem is with Qt apps (VLC, QTerminal, etc). Their menubars don't show up in the panel's appmenu.

I use a custom theme for GTK and would like to use the same for all Qt apps. The problem is that in qt5ct and in qt6ct the only style options available are Fusion and Windows. After installing qtcurve it does show some GTK2 themes but not the custom theme that I want to set. I also came to know that qtconfig has been removed since Qt5.


I've been searching for solutions for quite a while now but nothing has worked so far.
These are my OS specs:

Distribution: Kali GNU/Linux x86_64 (Debian based)
Desktop Environment: Xfce 4.18
Window Manager: Xfwm4
GTK version: 3.24.43

Please provide me some useful information about this.
